# Delete partially uncovered slides from a PDF presentation/Beamer?

Tags: pdf, beamer

I often have to work on PDF converted presentations where the author wanted to show only part of each slide on every page (e.g. only the problem was shown with a blank space underneath, then the next page (same slide) would have the same problem but a solution filling the previously blank space).

This is nice when presenting live, but not when going back and forth between slides (sometimes 7 pages between two slides).

**Question:** Is there a way to modify the PDF so that it only shows complete slides without all the intermediate pages ? 
Maybe with a web converter, a free app or a python script ?

Comment: x-site duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/543548/36296

Comment: Big thanks ! Exactly what I was looking for